# How to edit my record in database

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to edit my record in db but somehow I just add another record. What I need to change in my code?

I tried to write `db.NewsPortals.Update(image);` instead of `db.NewsPortals.Add(image);` but Visual Studio doesn't recognize that. Why?

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Edit(int id, NewsPortalViewModel model)
    {
        var validImageTypes = new string[]
        {
         "image/gif",
         "image/jpeg",
         "image/pjpeg",
         "image/png"
        };

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var image = db.NewsPortals.Find(id);

            if (image == null)
            {
                return new HttpNotFoundResult();
            }

            image.Id = model.Id;
            image.Title = model.Title;
            image.Description = model.Description;

            if (model.ImageFile != null && model.ImageFile.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                var uploadDir = "~/Image";
                var imagePath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath(uploadDir), model.ImageFile.FileName);
                var imageUrl = model.ImageFile.FileName;
                model.ImageFile.SaveAs(imagePath);
                image.ImageUrl = imageUrl;
            }

            db.NewsPortals.Add(image);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(model);
    }
```

Comment: The code you shared is adding a new record. You need to change that to udpate an existing record. Get the entity using the id, update the proeprty values and save back.

Answer (score 0):

If you remove this line it should work.

```
db.NewsPortals.Add(image);
```